# Google Material Ripple effect not working with Sveltejs

Tags: material-design, svelte

I tried to experiment with Google Material on my SvelteJS web app.

After many tries I finally was able to show the button at least as shown below.

[image]

Now, my problem is when I clicked the button I did not see the ripple effect.
However, when I looked at the Dev Tools I could see that the ripple effect is at least added as a class in my button as shown below.

[image]

I followed [Google Material's documentation](https://material.io/develop/web/components/buttons/) including applying ripple for a button but to no avail.

Below is my **Button.svelte** implementation for Google Material:

```
<script>
    import { onMount } from 'svelte';
  import {MDCRipple} from '@material/ripple';

  onMount(async () => {
        const buttonRipple = new MDCRipple(document.querySelector('.mdc-button'));
    });

</script>

<div class="mdc-touch-target-wrapper">
  <button class="mdc-button mdc-button--raised">
    <div class="mdc-button__ripple"></div>
    <span class="mdc-button__label">Contained Button</span>
  </button>
</div>

<style lang="scss">
    @import "./theme-mui.scss";

    .mdc-button {
      padding: 1em 1.2em;
    }
</style>
```

Also here is my **theme-mui.scss** :

```
@use "@material/button";
@use "@material/ripple";

@include button.core-styles;
```

Answer (score 1):

No guarantee that it solves your problem (because I can't reproduce easily), but at least it's a 'sveltier' way of solving the problem. We shouldn't use `document.querySelector`, there's a nicer way.

We can bind the HTML element to a local variable. And then we can use the reactive short hand to trigger statement when the bound value is updated

```
<script>
  import { onMount } from 'svelte';
  import { MDCRipple } from '@material/ripple';

  let button;
  $: MDCRipple.attachTo(button);
</script>

<div class="mdc-touch-target-wrapper">
  <button bind:this={button} class="mdc-button mdc-button--raised">
    <div class="mdc-button__ripple"></div>
    <span class="mdc-button__label">Contained Button</span>
  </button>
</div>
```

Now the initialization is not running on mount and on each element with that class that it finds but only on this element and only when it's 'present'.

Comment: I am new to svelte and I thank you for reminding how to do it in sveltier way and I appreciate it. And unfortunately this one does not work. In fact no button is shown altogether. But again thanks for taking the time to answer and more so in svelte way. By the way I also found the solution. If I remove the new keyword it works. I don't know why, when the document from Google says otherwise.

Comment: Interesting. I never used it, looked in their docs and also read that this can be either done with 'new MDCRipple(...)' or 'MDCRipple.attachTo(...)'. Glad that it works now, I update my answer (for the good code)

Comment: Yes, that's one option using `attachTo()`. But in my case, it was simply using `MDCRipple(button)` inside the `onMount` lifecycle.